# Cannot properly read coordinates for d3 chart - syntax error?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm sorry for the title, I could not think of a better one.
So I have a working function for drawing a path:

```
 settings.g.selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .join(
            enter => enter.append("path")
                .datum(d => getPathCoordinates(d,features)) //returns an object with X,Y pairs
                .attr("d", line)
                .attr("stroke-width", 3)
                .attr("stroke", (_, i) => colors[i])
                .style("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.65)
                .attr("opacity", 0.95)
        );
```

Now, I would like to draw a small circle at each point of the lines, so using the very same coordinates obtained using the getPathCoordinates function:

```
   settings.g.selectAll("node")
        .data(data)
        .join(
            enter => enter.append("circle")
            .datum(d => getPathCoordinates(d,features))
            .attr("cx", d => d.x)  //I guess these two are wrong
            .attr("cy", d => d.y)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
        )
```

When I replace the cx and cy values with a static number, it works. So the problem is how to read the coordinates properly.

I tried various approaches but none worked.

Comment: Can you post the code of `getPathCoordinates` and a sample of your `data` ?